# Swift guard else called on dictionary key with NULL value

Tags: swift, dictionary, guard

If I have a Dictionary returned from a NSNotification containing the following

```
print(notificationObj.object)
Optional({
    age = "<null>";
    names =     (
        David
    );
})
```

Then the guard else is called when trying to assign this to a variable:

```
guard let categories = notificationObj.object as? [String:[String]] else {
  // Gets to here
  return
}
```

How can I handle the case where a Dictionary key is null.

Comment: Please specify the type of the Dictionary. It cannot be `[String:[String]]` because such a dictionary cannot contain `nil` values by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary does contain ...

```
Optional({
    age = "<null>";
    names =     (
        David
    );
})
```

... and ...

- `age = ...` is `String = String` (value is single `String`),
- `names = ( ... )` is `String = [String]` (value is array of `String`s).

You can't cast it to `[String:[String]]` because the first pair doesn't fit this type. This is the reason why your `guard` statement hits `else`.

Hard to answer your question. Dictionary contains `names`, you want `categories`, `names` key does contain `David`, which doesn't look like category, ... At least you know why `guard` hits `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is not very clear.

However **IF**

- You have a dictionary declared as follow `[String:[String]]`
- And you want manage the scenario where a given key is not present

Like this

```
let devices : [String:[String]] = [
    "Computers": ["iMac", "MacBook"],
    "Phones": ["iPhone 6S", "iPhone 6S Plus"]
]
```

Then you can at least 2 solutions

### 1. conditional unwrapping

```
if let cars = devices["Car"] {
    // you have an array of String containing cars here 
} else {
    print("Ops... no car found")
}
```

### 2. guard let

```
func foo() {
    guard let cars = devices["Car"] else {
        print("Ops... no car found")
        return
    }
    // you have an array of String containing cars here...
    cars.forEach { print($0) }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears that your printed notificationObject.object is constructed from a JSON string that looks like this:

`"{ \"age\": null, \"names\":[\"David\"] }"`

The reason that you are hitting your else clause is because age is actually a nil, and not a valid String array.  I tried using `[String: [String]?]` and `[String: NSArray?]` neither of which seem to work. The type is actually an NSNull (which inherits from NSObject).

So you can cast to `[String: AnyObject]` and check for NSArray like this:

```
if let categories = j as? [String: AnyObject] where (categories["age"] is NSArray) {
    print("age was array")
} else {
    print("age is probably null")
}
```

You might be better off if your notification object simply omitted the "age" property when the value is null.  Then you would be able to cast to `[String: [String]]`.