# How to handle JSON response with nil using guard in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, null, swift3

I just want to ask how to handle JSON return with null values in Swift.
I used guard for unwrapping the values, but if the JSON has a null value like in the example below, guard will not be executed

I also want to know proper way of using a guard. Is it okay to use multiple conditions in one guard? Like in my sample code below?

```
{
  "error_code": "0",
  "error_description": [],
  "status": true,
  "results": {
  "id": 25,
  "email": "jaundelacruz@yahoo.com",
  "created_at": "2016-12-10T15:54:03.779Z",
  "updated_at": "2016-12-15T06:41:49.432Z",
  "first_name": "Juan",
  "last_name": "Cruz",
  "middle_name": "Dela",
  "nickname": "joe",
  "option_nickname": null,
  "age": 24,
  "gender": "Male",
  "mobile_number": "639959283721",
  "photo_url": {
  "url": null
  },
  "school": "University of the Philippines",
  "user_address": null,
  "city": "Quezon City",
  "country": null,
  "longtitude": 121.0621301,
  "latitude": 14.5832954,
  "facebook_user_id": null,
  "device_token": null,
  "token": "YrxVEWUMYxieFy7PEsAn",
  "is_sent": false,
  "show_nickname": false
},
"error": []
```

}

Here's my code:

```
func UserLogin(facebookID: String) -> Void {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    let urlString = Constants.baseURL + Constants.apiURL + Constants.loginUrl
    let params:Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
        "facebook_id": facebookID as AnyObject
    ]

    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                let userjson = JSON(data: response.data!)
                let results = userjson["results"].dictionaryValue
                guard let auth_token = results["token"]?.string,
                    let userid = results["id"]?.int,
                    let firstname = results["first_name"]?.string,
                    let lastname = results["last_name"]?.string,
                    let nickname = results["nickname"]?.string,
                    let city = results["city"]?.string,
                    let photo = results["photo_url"]?["url"]else{

                        //nil
                    return
                }

                //The Process will not continue from here if the JSON response has a null value)

                self.userdefault.saveUserToken(authToken: auth_token)
                self.userdefault.setUserID(userID: userid)
                self.userdefault.setuserFirstName(userFName: firstname)
                self.userdefault.setuserLastName(userLName: lastname)
                self.userdefault.setuserNickName(userNName: nickname)
                self.userdefault.setuserCity(userCity: city)

                self.GotoMainNavigation()

            case .failure(let error):
                print("susb \(error)")

                self.getFacebookInfo()

            }
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your `guard` expression is perfectly fine and filters all `null` values except in the last line. Assuming the `url` is also a string you have to check

```
let photo = results["photo_url"]?["url"]?.string ...
```

but consider that the `guard` expression will only be evaluated to true if **all** optional bindings succeed.

For example if the `photo` value is supposed to be optional put it **after** the guard expression and use the nil coalescing operator:

```
let photo = results["photo_url"]?["url"]?.string  ?? ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 data =     {
        results =         {
            resultsData =             (
                                {
                    a = "A";
                    b = "B";
                    c = "C":
                }
            );
        };
};
```

guard is a new conditional statement that requires execution to exit the current block if the condition isn’t met. Any new optional bindings created in a guard statement’s condition are available for the rest of the function or block, and the mandatory else must exit the current scope, by using return to leave a function, continue or break within a loop, or a @noreturn function

```
guard let data = response["data"] as? [String:AnyObject],let resultsObj = response["results"] as? [String:AnyObject],let resultsData = results["resultsData"] as? [String:AnyObject] else{

   return
 }
```

Comment: what if "a" is null? Does a guard returns the other value?

Comment: Check This :-  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051886/swift-guard-else-called-on-dictionary-key-with-null-value]